# Animating button position change Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints

[3 Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBwY.png)
Currently I am trying to change the position of 2 buttons by tapping the third one.

```
`@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if checked {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.taskButton.center = self.addButton.center
                self.habitButton.center = self.addButton.center
                sender.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
            checked = false
        } else {
           // sender.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "CancelButton"), for: .normal)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 4.0)
                self.taskButton.center = self.taskButtonCenter
                self.habitButton.center = self.habitButtonCenter
            }
            checked = true
    }
        }`
```

This method is working only if I'm not using constraints. I don't know why, but if I am using it to run on a different device, the buttons are moving to a crazy position. Please help me find a better solution! Thanks
PS: I'm a begginer and I'm still trying to understand constraints!

Comment: Please show the constraints and the position you want to move on the screen.

Comment: Because you are using CGRect attribute for your animation... center is not auto layout attribute...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxBwY.png I have 3 buttons. When I tap the X button, I want the other 2 to go under the X button with animation.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints can also be outlets, and you should use them that way for animations if you're using autolayout. For example, I'll assume you position your button with `topMargin` and `leftMargin` constraints.

Your hypothetical code for animating the change would look like this then:

```
topMargin.constant += 50
leftMargin.constant += 50

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The code above would move the object placed by these constraints by 50 points to the right and down (anywhere actually, depending on how you place the constraints).